# How do I know if directive is enclosed in a container with ng-if = false?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am developing a custom directive and now I need to handle ng-if.  This is easy enough when ng-if is on the directive it self.  However when ng-if is on an enclosing container element my compile function fails with run time errors.

Question is: what is the best and most efficient way to know, inside the compile function of a directive, that the directive is enclosed within a container with ng-if is false OR an expression that evaluates to false.

For example:

```
<div ng-if="false">
    <my-directive></my-directive> 
</div>
```

And another example:

```
<div ng-if="somescopeValue > 300">
    <my-directive></my-directive> 
</div>
```

Maybe the answer is using jquery to traverse the dom and find a parent with 
an ng-if attribute but I was wondering if there is another more "angular" way of doing this.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? This seems to go against the purpose of a directive by making it aware of it's parent.

Answer (score 1):

Your directive shouldn't rely on knowing whether it is encapsulated in a ng-if expression. That breaks the principle of 'Separation of Concerns' and deteriorates code re-use. Consider redesigning your custom directive in such a way that it needs not be aware of its host elements, in the same fashion that all components (should) work.

Comment: This is a  directive encapsulating text box behavior for some specialized needs. Inside the compile function we check that the directive is enclosed within a form tag. This check fails for ng-if = false. So maybe we just need to remove this validation

Answer (score 0):

If you are using same scope as parent controller or directive then you are able to access same variable in your directive(here **my-directive**) also. If this is not a case then you need to write code to access parent element in link function of **my-directive**. You will get directive element in link function as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how the error happens, because when your directive is inside `ng-if="false"`, your directive won't get called at all - all compile, link and controller function in the directive will only run as soon as your directive gets added in DOM.

Perhaps your error can be solved by initializing something in case your directive is not added.